# MongoDB Autocomplete index doesn't get result

Tags: java, mongodb, search, autocomplete, mongodb-atlas

I have a collection which name called 'airport' and i have Atlas Auto Complete index you can see JSON config below.

```json
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": false,
    "fields": {
      "name": [
        {
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "foldDiacritics": false,
          "maxGrams": 7,
          "minGrams": 2,
          "type": "autocomplete"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and this is my Document record

```json
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "63de588c7154cc3ee5cbabb2"
  },
  "name": "Antalya Airport",
  "code": "AYT",
  "country": "TR",
  "createdDate": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1675516044323"
    }
  },
  "updatedDate": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1675516044323"
    }
  },
  "updatedBy": "VISITOR",
  "createdBy": "VISITOR",
}
```

And This is my MongoDB Query

```java
public List<Document> autoCompleteAirports(AutoCompleteRequest autoCompleteRequest) {
        return database.getCollection(AIRPORT).aggregate(
                Arrays.asList(new Document("$search",
                        new Document("index", "airportAutoCompleteIndex")
                                .append("text",
                                        new Document("query", autoCompleteRequest.getKeyword())
                                                .append("path", "name")
                                )))
        ).into(new ArrayList<>());
    }
```

So, when i type "antalya" or "Antalya", this works. But when i type "Antaly" or "antal" there is no result.

Any solution ?

i tried change min and max grams settings on index